# THREE.BufferGeometry error with stemkoski Particle Engine

Tags: three.js, particle-engine

I was trying to use stemkoski's [particle engine](https://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com/blob/master/Three.js/js/ParticleEngine.js) in my own project (his example of using the particle engine can be found [here](http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Particle-Engine.html) ). I have received an error of `three.min.js:474 THREE.ShaderMaterial: attributes should now be defined in THREE.BufferGeometry instead`. After tracking down the source, I noticed that it is the version of threejs he used in his library that is different from mine. Whereas I used `http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js`, he used a [different version](https://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com/blob/master/Three.js/js/Three.js) (looking into the file, I believe it's version 60 )

What I have tried so far:

1. Used the `three.min.js` from threejs.org/build but change the following in the `ParticleEngine.js`

   ```
   this.particleGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
   ```

   to

   ```
   this.particleGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
   ```

This pretty much gives me the same errors

2. Used his version of three.js instead, says `renderer.setPixelRatio` and `geometry.scale` they are not functions (Because I used these two functions in my own project)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the squarefeet/ShaderParticleEngine instead of the stemkoski and it works well. I gave anoter piece of information in a previous answer but it was deleted by Brad as considered as not helpful. I believe it was as it says that updating three.js to r79 was not a solution.